# Using IF without an ELSE condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I'm trying to use the below query to update some data only if @rowcount is greater than 0. However, its executing the update statement even when @RowCount is 0. Can someone help whats wrong in here please? I would like to do nothing if @RowCount is 0.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

```
    TRUNCATE TABLE Count1
    DECLARE @RowCount AS INT

    --insert data in a temporary table
    SELECT YEAR, S_ID
    into #Count1 FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT D.YEAR, S_ID FROM SALES S JOIN TRANSACTIONS PT
    ON S.COMBINED_TXN_ID = PT.S_ID AND PT.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING'
    JOIN DATE D ON D.DAY = S.DAY AND PT.DAY = S.DAY
    WHERE
    S.SALES_CUSTOMER    !=   PT.CUSTOMER)Counter1;

    --Store the rowcount in a temporary variable
    SET @RowCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Count1) 

    --Fix the data with differences only if count>0
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE SALES
    SET SALES_CUSTOMER =  PT.CUSTOMER
    FROM SALES S
    JOIN TRANSACTIONS PT ON  S.COMBINED_TXN_ID = PT.S_ID
    JOIN DATE D ON D.DAY = S.DAY AND PT.DAY = S.DAY
    WHERE
    S_ID IN (SELECT S_ID FROM #Count1) 
    END;
```

Comment: you changed `@RowCount` (a variable declared by you) with `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT is not your @RowCount.

Comment: You are truncating Count1 and then using select into #Count1...seems like something is a bit off there. Perhaps you might consider using EXISTS here instead of looking at your row count. Or just fixing your update so it doesn't need the conditional check.

Comment: You don't even need this statement `SET @RowCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Count1)` since your `IF` statement is checking `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: My apologies for the typo with RowCount/ROWCOUNT. I've corrected that in the query.

Comment: Something is very wrong with this query. You have an alias of S for Sales but then you join a table named S and alias it as PT. Talk about confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use the same variable you have declared use `@rowcount`

```
DECLARE @recordCount INT

--insert data in a temporary table
SELECT YEAR
    ,S_ID
INTO #Count1
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT D.YEAR
        ,S_ID
    FROM SALES S
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS PT
        ON S.COMBINED_TXN_ID = PT.S_ID
            AND PT.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING'
    INNER JOIN DATE D
        ON D.DAY = S.DAY
            AND PT.DAY = S.DAY
    WHERE S.SALES_CUSTOMER != PT.CUSTOMER
    ) Counter1;

--Store the rowcount in a temporary variable
SELECT @recordCount = count(*)
FROM #Count1

--Fix the data with differences only if count>0
IF (@recordCount > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE SALES
    SET SALES_CUSTOMER = PT.CUSTOMER
    FROM SALES S
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS PT
        ON S.COMBINED_TXN_ID = PT.S_ID
    INNER JOIN DATE D
        ON D.DAY = S.DAY
            AND PT.DAY = S.DAY
    WHERE S_ID IN (
            SELECT S_ID
            FROM #Count1
            )
END
```

Answer (score 3):

[@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

Change system variable @@ROWCOUNT by your own variable @RowCount

```
--Store the rowcount in a temporary variable
SET @RowCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Count1) 

--Fix the data with differences only if count>0
IF  @RowCount > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. The problem indeed was that I was confusing @rowcount with @@ROWCOUNT. I changed the code and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the local variable `@RowCount` you defined yourself, with the global variable `@@ROWCOUNT` Microsoft defined for you (which you *can't* set).

So simply refer to the correct variable. Better yet: rename your local variable to avoid such confusion.

You don't even need the `if` at all, since the update wouldn't be executed if `#Count1` is empty as there are no records to fulfill the `where` clause (`WHERE S_ID IN ({empty result set})`).

Answer (score 1):

You could skip all the temp tables and checks and just do an update. Something like this should be the same thing as all the code you posted.

```
UPDATE S
SET SALES_CUSTOMER = PT.CUSTOMER
FROM SALES S
JOIN S PT ON S.COMBINED_TXN_ID = PT.S_ID
             AND PT.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLING'
JOIN DATE D ON D.DAY = S.DAY 
            AND PT.DAY = S.DAY
WHERE  S.SALES_CUSTOMER != PT.CUSTOMER
```